# Basic CSS not working with non-IE browsers from IIS8

Tags: css, iis-8

So this is probably about as basic as it gets and I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong.  I am using IIS on Windows 10 (for development\practice) and I have only two files in my web root: default.htm & style.css

**default.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="bodystuff">
            Stuff
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
#bodystuff {
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 5em;
}
```

My problem (and odds are it's something silly that I'm missing) is that when I open the page with IE (11 if that matters) it opens up fine and the stuff in my body properly renders using my style.css file.  However if I open the same web site up with Firefox the site is rendering as if I had no styles configured at all.

[image: strange]

Any suggestions on what I am missing to make it so that my CSS is used when opening the site with either IE or FF?

Comment: Check your developer console for warnings, and your network panel to ensure the CSS is requested and the correct response is given.

Comment: On the networking tab I get a 200 for getting style.css, however on the console I get two warnings:


* Unexpected end of file while searching for ',' or '{'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. style.css:1:30

* Unexpected end of file while searching for closing } of invalid rule set. style.css:1:30

Comment: Click on the request for the `style.css` file, and check the "Response" tab. Sounds like there is something unexpected in the selector.

Comment: Thanks for looking @AlexanderO'Mara !  I took the error\warning from the code\CSS tab and did the natural thing and searched for it and found [this post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=595318) which suggests that it may be an encoding issue.  I recreated my files as UTF8 (making sure they're both the same encoding) and not it works....strange!

Comment: Ah yes, some Windows software likes to make text files needlessly large with silly things like byte-order-marks and multi-byte characters which are generally not well supported. Stick to UTF8, anything else is just bad.

Answer (score 0):

The end cause was that the file encoding for my default.htm and style.css files were different.  I recreated the files using UTF8 and now it works.  It would appear that Firefox is quite sensitive to the file encoding between CSS and HTML documents.  I found the solution thanks to @AlexanderO'Mara pointing me to Firefox's developer console which revealed a warning that I then searched for and found a discussion about [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=595318).